# why we need Matrix for 2D transformations

Tags: android, kotlin, matrix, canvas, imageview

Can some one please explain me why we need matrix for image rotation, scaling etc.
We can do all the basic function also without matrix like set the position, rotate an image all that so why we need matrix for that ? some reference will be very helpful thank you for advance.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If you want to implement 2D transformations without using a matrix, you're free to do so.

Comment: Using matrices for transformations is just a tool. It's a convenience. A means to an end. It's the same like asking "Why do we need a fork to eat food?"